# Regex match that will ignore punctuation within the string

Tags: ruby, regex

** edited **

I'm trying to compare one name from source A (`ST MARYS MEDICAL CENTER`) with another name from source B (`St. Mary's Medical Center: Welcome`).  A and B are not arrays.

I would like to retain `St. Mary's Medical Center`.  In essence, I need to confirm that they are the same institution and 'normalize' the value.

I would like to ignore case, all periods (`.`), and all apostrophes (`'`).  If there is a match, I'd like to retain the **matching** value from B.

For example:

```
> a = "ST MARYS MEDICAL CENTER"
=> "ST MARYS MEDICAL CENTER"

> b = "St. Mary's Medical Center: Welcome"
=> "St. Mary's Medical Center: Welcome"

# need help here
> re = /#{a}[^'.]*/i
=> /ST MARYS MEDICAL CENTER[^'.]*/i

> re.match(b)[0]
=> "St. Mary's Medical Center"
```

Assuming that I get the correct regex, will the match include the punctuation?

Comment: Sounds more like you should canonicalize them both to a spaceless, punctuationless, caseless form and then simply check if they are equal.

Comment: Could you do a simple replace on `b` so only letters and spaces are kept?  Search: `[^a-zA-Z0-9\ ]` Replace with "nothing".

Comment: so `a` and `b` are actually arrays?

Comment: So when you say "retain the matching value from B" does that mean replace each value in A with a B match, keeping non-matching values in A? Or do you want as output only the matches, discarding non-matches?

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest not bothering with the regex?

Instead, try stripping punctuation and upcasing `b`, then compare the strings directly to see if they match.

```
 b.upcase.sub(/[^\w\s]/, '') == a
```

Comment: This is the more common-sense way of doing it. Regex are great for some things, but this question shouldn't bother with them.

Comment: `\w` actually means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` which is probably not really what the OP means. Maybe some of the POSIX character-set definitions would offer better granularity. And, `[^\w\s]` is better written `[\W\S]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `String#scan` like this

```
a = "St. Mary's Medical Center"
match = "ST MARYS MEDICAL CENTER"
a.upcase.scan(/[^.']*/).join == match
#=> true
```

Comment: This is forcing the code to do a lot of work just to match. As `a` grows the code is going to slow down greatly. For short strings it'll be contained but long strings will make the `scan` and `join` costly.